# Mass email a group of contact

Tags: custom-object, contact, campaign, massemailmessage

I created a custom object named `ContactGroup` where I can add `Contact`. A `Contact` can have many `ContactGroup` and a `ContactGroup` can contain many `Contact` (so this is a n-n relationship).

Now I would like to send a mass email to all `Contact` of a specified `ContactGroup`. Unfortunately, in the filter view (Contact/Mass Email Contacts/Create new view), I don't see a `ContactGroup` field on my `Contact` object where I could filter with a 'Include' operator or something similar.

I do have the same problem if I'm creating a campaign (it is actually the same user interface to create the filter view).

What is the workaround to mass email `Contacts` of a specified `ContactGroup`?

Comment: Probably Visualforce and Apex would be the cleanest methods.

Comment: Maybe, but it is a big investment in term of work... not sure to have a budget for that ;-) I would prefer a solution that is more "built-in"

Answer (score 2):

I think you need a Junction Object that has **two** `Master-Detail Relationships`:

1. Master-Detail Relationship with `Contact`
2. Master-Detail Relationship with `ContactGroup__c`

Maybe call this Junction Object `Contact_Junction__c`.  The Junction Object allows for a many-many relationship between two other objects.  Try it out, and see what your related-lists look like.

For reports, you *may* need create your Report Type that contains all of the objects (`Contact`, `ContactGroup__c`, `Contact_Junction__c`).